# Support for OpenGL 4.3 for nVidia on 12.04.2 (or any version)?

Tags: nvidia, opengl

Are the OpenGL 4.3 features of the latest nVidia cards supported yet in the drivers?

Comment: What features are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia has recently released the driver that supports OpenGL 4.4, and you are more then welcome to beta test it.

https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver

Obviously, there is no support for it in Ubuntu yet.